# Corel Draw API (Java/C#)

Tags: c#, java, api, coreldraw

I am wondering if there is an API from Corel Draw for Java or similar. A friend of mine would need a small program that edits some pics. It has to be Corel Draw but there is no restriction in the Programming language (Java or C# preffered...)

Unfortunatly i didn't find Anything helpful in the Internet..maybe some of you guys know more?

Comment: (People still use Corel products...? I doubt there is an API for it, but perhaps there is a way to convert one vector format, with an API to created/alter it, to/from the "Corel Draw" format, or another intermediate vector format.)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you write some macro with use VB. You can find all information in pdf document in below location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Corel\Corel Graphics 12\Programs

PDFs: **dvba_pg.pdf**

PP VBA Object Model.pdf: **CorelDRAW VBA Object Model.pdf**

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The best I found is to use VBscripts.

In cas you are still interested, take a look a the code below. 
The scripts (started from java) takes 2 arguments : a source file and a destination file, and makes some manipulation on the source file, before saving it to the destination.

Limitation of this script is that it relies on "CorelDraw x6". You can write it more generic and looking for the various CorelDraw OLE objects.

Limitation of this mechanism is that not everything can be done of works with VB (I never achieved to get a CorelDraw page's size !!!)

Code:

```
<package>
    <job id="Main">
        <reference object="CorelDraw.Application" version="16.0" />
        <script language="VBScript">
            Option Explicit

            Dim app

            ' Parameters
            Dim source, dest
            if ( Wscript.Arguments.count<2) Then
                    Err.Raise 2, "MakeThumb", "Invalid paremeters count"
                    Wscript.echo "Invalid paremeters count"
                    Wscript.quit -999
                    end if


            source= Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
            dest= Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

            'Wscript.echo source
            'Wscript.echo dest

            ' Initialisation
            set app= nothing
            On Error resume next
            ' Retrieval of an existing instance
            Set app = GetObject(, "CorelDraw.Application.16")
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' No existing instance, creatoing a new one
            If (app is nothing) Then
                    Err.Clear
                    On Error resume next
                    Set app = CreateObject("CorelDraw.Application.16")
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    End If
            If (app Is Nothing) Then
                    Err.Raise 2, "MakeThumb", "Impossible to open Corel Draw"
                    'stop
                    Wscript.quit -998
                    end if

            app.visible=true
            Dim doc
            set doc = app.OpenDocument(source)

            ' Trying to get source document's size

            'Dim cs
            'Set cs = CreateObject( "CorelDRAW.CorelScript" )
            Dim pg
            Set pg = doc.pages.Item(1)

            doc.unit=5 'unit=pixels

            Dim h0, w0

            on error resume next
            ' if it fails, I assume the dimention are an A4

            h0=pg.SizeHeight
            w0=pg.SizeWidth
            if (err<>0) then
                w0=2480
                h0=3508
                end if
            on error goto 0


            Dim h, w, s, r
            'Wscript.echo "h orig=" + CStr(h0) + ",w orig=" + CStr(w0) + " unit=" + CStr(doc.Unit)

            h = doc.ToUnits(h0, cdrPixel)
            w = doc.ToUnits(w0, cdrPixel)

            s = h * w
            r = Sqr(500990 / s)
            'Wscript.echo "h=" + CStr(h) + ",w=" + CStr(w) + ",s=" + CStr(s) + ", r=" + CStr(r)

            Dim h2, w2
            h2 = h * r
            w2 = w * r

            'Wscript.echo "h2=" + CStr(h2) + ",w2=" + CStr(w2)

            Dim exportFilter
            Set exportFilter = doc.ExportBitmap( _ 
            dest, cdrPNG, cdrCurrentPage, cdrRGBColorImage, w2, h2, 72, 72, _ 
            cdrNormalAntiAliasing, False, False, True, False, cdrCompressionNone, Nothing, Nothing)
            exportFilter.Finish

            doc.close 
            app.quit

            Set app = Nothing 
            Set doc = Nothing
            Wscript.quit 0

        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```